# How to unit test angular guard with observable subscription in constructor

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-services

I'm trying to unit test an angular guard which pipes an observable that belongs to an authentication service. The subscription happens in the guard `canActivate()` method.

I'm using a jasmine spy on the authentication service observable to return values, but the spy is never called in my unit test.

When testing a component, I use `fixture.detectChanges()`, but for this guard I can't find a way to test that it returns the right thing according to the observable value.

auth-guard.ts:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private router: Router
  ) {}

  canActivate(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.authService.isAuthenticated$.pipe(
      map(e => {
        if (e) {
          return true;
        }
      }),
      catchError((err) => {
        this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        return of(false);
      })
    );
  }
}
```

auth.service.ts:

```js
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {

  private isAuthenticated = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  get isAuthenticated$(): Observable<boolean> { return this.isAuthenticated.asObservable(); }

  ...
}
```

auth-guard.spec.ts:

```js
describe('Authuard', () => {

  let authGuard: AuthGuard;
  let authService: jasmine.SpyObj<AuthService>;

  beforeEach(() => {

    const authServiceSpy = jasmine.createSpyObj('AuthService', ['isAuthenticated$']);

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [
        AuthGuard,
        { provide: AuthService, useValue: authServiceSpy }
      ]
    });

    authGuard = TestBed.get(AuthGuard);
    authService = TestBed.get(AuthService);
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(authGuard).toBeDefined();
  });

  /* This test fails */
  it('should return false when not authenticated', () => {
    authService.isAuthenticated$.and.returnValue(of(false));

    authGuard.canActivate().subscribe(canActivate => {
        expect(canActivate).toBe(false);
    });
  });
});
```

The second test fails with `this.authService.isAuthenticated$.pipe is not a function`. The value returned by the spy on isAuthenticated$ is not taken.

How can I test that the guard returns the right value when the observable value return by the authentication service changes? Is it possible to do it with jasmine spies?

Comment: Would you mind letting me know if my answer worked ?

Answer (score 2):

Try `throwError` as below:

```
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';

it('should return false when not authenticated', () => {
    spyOn(authService,'isAuthenticated$').and.returnValue(throwError('error'));

    authGuard.canActivate().subscribe(canActivate => {
        expect(canActivate).toBeFalsy();
});
```